# How to create tables for flask app using peewee orm without double quotes in postgresql

Tags: python, peewee

I'm new to peewee orm.

Peewee uses double quotes when creating tables making it unnecessarily difficult to do select statements through psql shell. This goes for django's orm as well.

What I really want is a simple:

```
select username,password from user;
```

Instead I'm required to do

```
select "username", "password" from "user";
```

I've seen people use sqlalchemy which doesn't require the double quotes. Is there any way for me to turn off the double quotes when creating tables through the orm?

Thanks!

Comment: PostgreSQL folds unquoted identifiers to lower case so `select c from t` should be the same as `select "c" from "t"` as long as `c` and `t` are lower case.

Comment: **Always show the exact text of any error messages, along with the exact SQL that produced them**. In this case I suspect you're actually seeing mixed-case tables, eg `"UserName"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double quotes are not part of the actual table/column names. They are simply there so you won't get error messages with names that collide with reserved keywords.

When querying something from the shell you can safely omit them assuming the name does not require quotes because of the reason I just mentioned.

Comment: Hmm...could it be that the I cannot use the table user as one of my models because postgres has a default usertable set up already?

Comment: All internal tables start with `pg_`

Comment: Yes, `user` is a reserved table in postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a table named "user" with postgres:

```
psql (9.3.2)
Type "help" for help.

peewee_test=# create table user (id serial);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: create table user (id serial);
                     ^

peewee_test=# create table users (id serial);
CREATE TABLE
```

As noted, the quotes are there to prevent issues if you use a column that shares its name with a reserved word.